# Will using jQuery's .click() event handler to register a Google Analytics 'send' method work correctly?

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

When tracking custom Google Analytics events, I usually see the javascript  implementation where the `send` method call is applied directly to the html element, like this:

```
<a href="/about.html" id="about-link" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'navigation', 'click', 'About Link');">About Us</a>
```

Is it also possible to register the event using jQuery's `click()` method to trigger the GA 'send' method, like this?

```
$('#about-link').click(function() { 
    ga('send', 'event', 'navigation', 'click', About Link); 
});
```

I have done this and can see the custom events registering correctly in the Google Analytics Admin screens, but I'm concerned that there's the possibility that the browser might load the new page first before the GA 'send' method finishes registering the event with GA, which would mean that not all events are being registered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this should be fine, many people use jQuery that way and you do not hear that much complaints.

PLus with browsers that support it [sendBeacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) is (AFAIK) used as the default method to send data, and since sendBeacon has not to wait for a server response it works reliably even if your users follow the link.

If you are worried that you loose data you can do the redirect in a [hitcallback](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#hitCallback), i.e. a function that is called as after the tracking call has been sent, and do a redirect to the link target in there.

Comment: Thanks, Eike! This really helps me out.